# Pattern matching in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL database column for uploaded content [Mime types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type). This column contains string values in the form:

```
image/jpeg
image/gif
video/mpeg
video/mp4
```

Is there a SQL query where I can select all rows with the 'image' prefix? Or do I have to hard code each value?

> WHERE mime_type IN ('image/png','image/gif', ... )

Hard coding these values will make the script hard to maintain when future mime types are declared. The database already filters on input but adding a new column for grouping is out of my hands.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized it didn't really address the core question. But if you look at this fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ab12/1 , you'll see that the `LIKE` is not as optimal as the join even when proper indexes are created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WHERE mime_type LIKE 'image%'`

As simple as that. `%` acts as a wildcard.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `LIKE` operator

`WHERE mime_type LIKE 'image/%'`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like